# Posterior for Normal likelihood and uniform prior on variance

Tags: statistics, bayesian

Suppose we have data that is Normally distributed  $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$ with known mean and unknown variance . Then by conjugate priors, a Gamma can be placed on $\sigma^2$ to infer it.

I came across this paper ($\textit{Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models}$ - $\textit{Andrew Gelman}$) that advocates uniform prior though it is for hierarchical models. Which prior should I use? Also how do I calculate posterior with likelihood of N Normally distributed data samples and a uniform prior on variance?

Comment: I would use a Gaussian prior... both because it is principled, and because the calculations are simpler.

Comment: Huh?  "Posterior for Normal likelihood and *uniform prior on variance*" and "I'm using a *half normal for variance*".  Huh?

Comment: I'm pointing out your contradiction:  *uniform* or *half normal*.  Please decide and let us all know.

Comment: Since you suggested a Gaussian prior, I plan to use a half Normal for variance. Thanks. Hope this helps.